# Getting this error _csv.Error: sequence expected in Python

Tags: python, csv, append

I am trying to write a python script called header.py where I have a list of headers which is:-

```
header = ['name', 'age', 'gender']
```

I am trying to append a header to it and write it in a csv file.

Here is my code snippet:-

```
import csv  
header = ['name', 'age', 'gender']
updated_csv_writer = csv.writer(open("updatedQueryOutput.csv", "w"),delimiter = ',')
appendAdd = header.append("address")
updated_csv_writer.writerow(appendAdd)
```

But I am getting this error:-

```
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code.
Any help?Thanks

Comment: I would also note that you will leak the file handle for updatedQueryOutput.csv - you could look into using `with` to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` mutates the list but doesn't return it, so you need to move the header.append statement out onto its own.  See this top-level example:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So you could modify your code like this:

```
import csv  
header = ['name', 'age', 'gender']
updated_csv_writer = csv.writer(open("updatedQueryOutput.csv", "w"),delimiter = ',')
header.append("address")
updated_csv_writer.writerow(header)
```

If you wanted to preserve the original value of `header`, you could always make a new list like this:

```
header_new = header + ['address']
```

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work! Please see the edited version. I tried that, same error.

Comment: As I said, `append` mutates the list - it doesn't create a new list.  So you need to pass in `header`.  Updated answer to include working code.